# How to remotely access a local parse server (parse port and server url)

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I made an app for my friends and I as well as a parse server. I know how to setup locally, but how do I allow us to connect remotely. I know how to setup port forwarding, but I'm not sure which port parse uses, and how to enter the serverURL in the app.

Answer (score 0):

The port can be determined by the **PORT** environment variable. 
If you will have a look on the index.js file of the parse server you will see the following line:

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
```

In this line parse server will try to get the port from the PORT env. variable and if not the default port will be 1337 so if you didn't specify and value under the PORT env. variable the port will be 1337

another important thing to notice is the **mouthPath** parameter so inside your parse server index.js you will see the following line:

```
var mountPath = process.env.PARSE_MOUNT || '/parse';
```

this line will try to get the mouthPath from the PARSE_MOUNT env. variable and it will is not exist the default will be /parse

so in your case after you deploy parse server successfully you should access it via the following URL:

http://{host}:{port}/{mouth_path}

and if you use only default values the URL will be:

http://{HOST}:1337/parse